# Select multiple rows by position without id

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, limit

In MySql I have a complex SELECT which returns a table of about 500k rows and without primary key.

**I would like to select 10 rows based on the different position they have in the resulting table, as efficiently as possible.**

I tried using LIMIT:
`SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5,1;`
efficient but select only one row.

I tried with UNION and LIMIT, but I have to do the complex SELECT several times:

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5,1)
  UNION
(SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1000,1)
  UNION
(SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 50000,1)
...
```

Is there a more efficient way to get what I want?

Comment: side note: SQL tables are orderless using LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: You are right, your approach is not optimal. Well, first of all you'll have to sort your data anyway, as Raymond has pointed out, And with your query the DBMS would probably order your data mutliple times only to get one position each time. Then you even use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` which tells the DBMS to look for duplicates in your results, although there can be no duplicates.

Comment: In an ideal world, the DBMS would look at your query and get the most efficient execution plan, no matter how it is written. But we are not there yet. Some other DBMS are already closer to that than MySQL is. Oracle's optimizer for instance is able to completeley re-write a query internally in order to find a better approach (it would use the row_number approach I am showing in my answer for your query and even know that it can stop sorting after having found the top 50001 rows).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
Sorting doesn't interest me so LIMIT is fine. Indeed, by not imposing an order, DBMS has the freedom to choose the most efficient. But if I apply LIMIT multiple times, I would like to be able to SELECT the table only once and then make sure it's always the same.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the order is arbitrary. That means that you could theoretically get the same rows you find at positions 6, 1001, and 50001 when you run the query once, at the positions 1, 2, and 3 when you run it a second time. It's all left to chance, so if you don't care which rows to get, why not just `LIMIT 10` right away?

Comment: The key problem is how to pick 10 rows at random.  Most techniques require a full table scan, or worse.  I have several nearly-random techniques here: [_Random_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the positions you must sort the data; there is no way around that. So, number your rows by the desired order and pick the positions you want:

```
select *
from
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by ...) as rn
  from table_name t
) numbered
where rn in (6, 1001, 50001);
```

Comment: No better than `RAND()`.

Comment: @Rick James: In my answer I assume that there *are* certain fixed positions in the result they want to access. This incudes a deterministic order (maybe by ID or datetime) that the OP may have assumed to get without an `ORDER BY`, which is wrong of course. So they would have to apply an `ORDER BY` for this, and in that case my query should be about the best approach. If they wanted three or ten random rows, why would they be so specific about the exact positions in the data set? I find it unlikely hence that they want `RAND()`.

Comment: Alas, MySQL does not have a way to step over rows to a specific "row number".  It scans the entire list checking for the desired `rn`.  Here's a metric for demonstrating such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts